# How get first row from duplicate values mysql query

Tags: mysql

My table with value

```
id  ssid_no  end_date
1   5415345  18/12/2020
2   4656845  18/12/2020
3   8554511  01/05/2019
```

I want to make group but eliminite dublicate and select first id row.
in example eliminate after group select id='1' row(1,2 row have dublicate select first one) and id= '3' row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, ssid_no, end_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ssid_no ORDER BY end_date) AS rownumber FROM ssid_no) t WHERE t.rownumber = 1;
```

This will return the first row for each id.

Comment: `FROM ssid_no` must be replaced by `FROM table_name`. Works perfectly then

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM your_table_name t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT min(id) as id
    FROM your_table_name
    GROUP BY `end_date`
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id;
```